# Simulate Service Crash In Emulator

Tags: android, service, android-emulator, crash

Does someone know how to simulate service crash in emulator ?
I have two services running in my application on Emulator, and I have to check what happens if a Service crashes..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257378/android-how-to-force-restart-service-os-killing-on-low-memory-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the service crash, all you need to do is to make it throw unhandled exception. 
If you write:
`int a = 3/0`
it will throw an exception, and the service will crash

Comment: @Ron-Thanks a lot mate! Let me try it .

Answer (score 0):

You can also stop service in Settings-Application-Running and choose your App/Service. This is not exactly crash, but stopping service during some work can cause also some troubles ;-)