# Automatic service restart after killing in application manager

Tags: android, service

I am trying to make a service in a separate process which should be restarted after manual stop in task manager. Return of START_STICKY in onStartCommand() doesn't work for me. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Activity starts the service like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    doStartService();

    super.onResume();
}

private void doStartService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
    doBindService();
}

private void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mBound = true;
}
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: generally if a service is killed forcibly, it takes time for the service to be restarted on its own as the parameters android considers include are the importance and the space.

Comment: see this ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257378/android-how-to-force-restart-of-a-service-os-killing-on-low-memory-behavior